# ¿Cómo llenar un jtable con datos de un txt? Java

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, jtable, txt

estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual hago uso de dos jtable, uno de ellos se debe llenar con nombres ya que es una lista de empresarios. Estos nombres los tengo en un txt dentro del proyecto para que sea solo hacer el llamado y que esos nombres se pasen al jtable.

Ya he manejado jtable antes pero no de una sola columna, entonces no sé si la cantidad de columnas que se usarán afecta en el correcto funcionamiento del código.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class Proyecto extends javax.swing.JFrame {

DefaultTableModel modelo;

int numEmp;
String[] nombres;

public Proyecto() {
    initComponents();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nombres.txt"));
        String linea;
        ArrayList<String> arlist = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            arlist.add(linea);
        }
        nombres = arlist.toArray(new String[arlist.size()]);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Archivo de texto no encontrado!");
    }

    String[][] datos = {};
    String[] titulos = {"Empresarios"};

    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(datos, titulos);

}                       

private void btnLlenarEmpresariosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    numEmp = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Cuántos empresarios desea agregar? 1-52"));
    if ((numEmp > 0) && (numEmp < 53)) { // El condicional es porque tengo en el txt exactamente 53 
                                         //nombres y necesito controlar que no se desborde el 
                                         //requerimiento
        for(int i = 0;i < numEmp;i++){
            Object [] fila = {nombres[i]};
            modelo.addRow(fila);
        }
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, la cantidad de dptos debe estar entre 1 y 52 inclusivos!", "IMPORTANTE", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        this.numEmp = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Cuántos empresarios desea agregar? 1 - 52"));
    }
}
```

El txt está organizado un nombre dejado del otro, con el fin de evitar usar el método .split()

Al teclear el boton "LlenarEmpresarios" no pasa nada, pero tampoco me muestra una excepción o error, gracias de antemano por cualquier guía que me puedan brindar, ya intenté colocando el try catch dentro del codigo del boton pero tampoco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno así una mirada rápida que le di y si es todo tu codigo nunca declaraste una `JTable` donde luego agregas tu modelo

```
JTable table = new JTable(modelo);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sé como pude olvidar eso!!